# Google Analytics - can I add some unique identifier for different pages?

Tags: html, google-analytics

I need to be able to pair `urls` of products with the products in a database so I can show for example visitors count for each product in admin using `Reporting GA API`

I could parse `urls` to get the ids since they are like

```
https://example.com/products/detail/<ID>/
```

but I'm curious if there is a way to pass some variable inside `html` so API returns this ID alongside `URL`,`sessions` etc.

Something like:

```
<meta name="ga:pageId" content="128">
```

Comment: Well you could always just put the value in the `<body id="">` or similar... though extracting that value will be no easier than extracting the value from the URL.

Comment: Are you using google tag manager. ?

Comment: This sounds like product detail view metric of enhanced ecommerce functionality, which can be reported by product id (SKU).

Comment: @Tushar yes we do, how we make it work?

Comment: @kgrg It's website in Django so there is no such thing...